# Unittests in Rust with WebAssembly

Tags: unit-testing, rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen, rust-wasm

I'm writing a frontend in `WASM` by using the `seed` framework.

I want to test one of my modules with unittests, but I can't make them to test `WASM` code. Here's my test suite:

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn check_non_wasm() {
        assert_eq!("test", "test");
    }

    #[test]
    fn check_home() {
        assert_eq!(Urls::new().home().to_string(), "/");
    }
}
```

The first tests passes, as there isn't used anything related to `WASM`. The other test fails with the following error:

```rust
thread 'urls::tests::check_home' panicked at 'cannot call wasm-bindgen imported functions on non-wasm targets'
```

If I'll run `cargo make test --chrome` it doesn't even see these tests.
I've tried to run `cargo test --target wasm32-unknown-unknown`, and it fails with following error:

```rust
could not execute process `C:\Users\djenty\w\frontend\target\wasm32-unknown-unknown\debug\deps\w_frontend-2b6de747c6501f70.wasm` (never executed)
```

`rustup` shows that the target is installed:

```
installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

wasm32-unknown-unknown
x86_64-pc-windows-msvc

active toolchain
----------------

stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc (default)
rustc 1.54.0 (a178d0322 2021-07-26)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Haven't used yet, but looks like there is a spesific `wasm-bindgen` test framework. [wasm-bindgen-test](https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/wasm-bindgen/wasm-bindgen-test/usage.html)